fvm flutter --version is different from fvm list
I am trying to set my flutter version to 3.10.2. I tried using fvm use 3.10.2.
When I run fvm list, I get:
Cache Directory:  /home/me/fvm/versions

3.19.3
3.10.2 (active)
3.3.1

But when running fvm flutter --version, i get:
Flutter 3.19.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 300451adae (vor 7 Tagen) • 2024-03-27 21:54:07 -0500
Engine • revision e76c956498
Tools • Dart 3.3.3 • DevTools 2.31.1

I run both commands in the same directory. This is a problem, because the fvm flutter pub run build_runner build command fails, due to the wrong version being used. Error I get is:
The current Dart SDK version is 3.3.3.

Because my-project requires SDK version 3.0.2, version solving failed.

How can I set my flutter version to 3.10.2.

from the root directory of your flutter project, run fvm use 3.10.2

If you are using window check your environment variable there you might have defined a static path to the flutter sdk which will be used when you run
flutter --version


I don't use fvm myself so I'm not sure why that is not working for you, but alternatively you can navigate to the directory where your flutter sdk is installed and do a
git checkout 3.10.2

for selecting the flutter version.
